# Registry API 32 vs 64bit, and VS2010 setup

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, registry, installation

We have a .net 4.0 app which uses a couple of registry keys and a vs2010 setup & deployment project which creates those keys @ setup

Problem - (default) RegEdit shows the keys exist but the .net code returns null on OpenSubKey with the correct path ( incl. the \ )

Which as it turns out is due to 32 & 64 bit registries per  [KB305097](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097)

and which requires code such as

```
RegistryKey someFunc()
{
    var r64o32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem  ? RegistryView.Registry64 :    
           RegistryView.Registry32);

    return r64o32.OpenSubKey(regKey);
}
```

However i cannot test the code above as I don't have a 32bit machine available but the app needs to be available on 32bit machines as well

so looking for help on -

1. is the approach above correct for both 64/32bit ?
2. does the setup created by vs2010 setup project install the defined registry
   entry on 64/32 registry based on the the machine ?
3. Any other gotchas ?

Comment: Is your app running in 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (AnyCPU) mode?

Comment: mixed mode, the .exe was in x86 and all dll's in anyCpu mode, don't know why the .exe was set to x86 !

Comment: Starting from VS2010, exe project template defaulted to x86. You have to add AnyCPU yourself. VS2008 and older defaulted to AnyCPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do special casing on the `RegistryView` as you are using `OpenBaseKey` this is asking for a specific view of the Registry regardless of how you compiled your application

```
RegistryKey r = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
                                                        RegistryView.Registry64);
```

Also remember that if you are on a 32bit machine, then OpenBaseKey will just fallback to Registry32